# Is there a way to move a file with the ability to cancel the move in the middle?

Tags: c#, winapi

I'm using `CopyFileEx` to copy files with that ability. Is there anything like it for moving files? Remember that not every move is fast – moving to a different drive is actually a copy.

The solution I have now is to copy-and-delete-the-original if the move is to a different root directory, and to simply move (and hope it's really just a change in the pointer to the file) if it's to the same root directory.

Is there a straightforward solution (like `CopyFileEx`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MoveFileTransacted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365241%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [MoveFileWithProgress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365242%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) might be more suitable?  I believe that can be cancelled.

```
BOOL WINAPI MoveFileWithProgress(
  __in      LPCTSTR lpExistingFileName,
  __in_opt  LPCTSTR lpNewFileName,
  __in_opt  LPPROGRESS_ROUTINE lpProgressRoutine,
  __in_opt  LPVOID lpData,
  __in      DWORD dwFlags
);
```

> When moving a file across volumes, if lpProgressRoutine returns PROGRESS_CANCEL due to the user canceling the operation, MoveFileWithProgress will return zero and GetLastError will return ERROR_REQUEST_ABORTED. The existing file is left intact.
>
> When moving a file across volumes, if lpProgressRoutine returns PROGRESS_STOP due to the user stopping the operation, MoveFileWithProgress will return zero and GetLastError will return ERROR_REQUEST_ABORTED. The existing file is left intact.

Comment: Thanks. What is the difference between them = what does "...as a transacted operation" mean?

Comment: If the move is for a whole directory for example, they either ALL succeed, or none of them do.  I believe that only applies to local NTFS moves though, not network moves.

Comment: Transacted means it's atomic. All or none.

Comment: @Cylindric: Depends on your version of Windows. With 7/2K8R2, you can have cross system transactions. You can actually link an SQL transaction with local filesystem and remote filesystem transactions. I've only read about the feature, not actually used it.

Comment: That's bonkers :)  There's some clever stuff coming down the line.

Comment: Win7/2K8R2 are still not mainstream enough, so I wouldn't target that feature  :P

Answer (score 2):

Use [MoveFileWithProgress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365242%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and return `PROGRESS_CANCEL` from the `lpProgressRoutine`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `SHFileOperation` API, see here for a .NET C# wrapper:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3282481/559144

and also refer here: http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32.SHFileOperation