# How do I delete a folder and it's contents, without putting them in the recycle bin?

Tags: c#, file-io

I am creating a program to run file I/O stress on a drive and when it is done, I want to delete the files, but don't want to put them in the recycle bin. Here is the code I have now:

```
    public static void DeleteDirectory(string target_dir)
    {
        //Delete the files and folders created during stress.
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(target_dir);
        string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(target_dir);
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            File.SetAttributes(file, FileAttributes.Normal);
            File.Delete(file);
        }
        foreach (string dir in dirs)
        {
            DeleteDirectory(dir);
        }
        Thread.Sleep(30);
        Directory.Delete(target_dir, true);
    }
```

But this  code just moves the files to the recycle bin. I don't want to add code to automatically empty the recycle bin as there may be files in there I don't want to delete (the files might belong to someone else).

NOTE: From the replies this has gotten so far, it seems people might be misunderstanding what I am trying to do here. When my program deletes files, it is sending them to the Recycle Bin. I do NOT want that to happen, I want to delete the files immediately. I do not see any way to tell the system to delete the files WITHOUT sending them to the Recycle Bin. I will never need to restore the files. It is defaulting to sending to the Recycle Bin, but I don't see any way to change this. Please, if possible, edit the code I have posted to have it delete the files immediately. I am a beginning to novice C# user.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282418/send-a-file-to-the-recycle-bin

Comment: How is an entirely opposite question a "duplicate"...?

Answer (score 7):

You are looking for [FileSystem.DeleteDirectory Method (String, UIOption, RecycleOption)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms127971.aspx)

> **recycle**
>
> Specifies whether or not the deleted file should be sent to the
>   Recycle Bin. Default is RecycleOption.DeletePermanently.