# How to show FileSystem.DeleteFile dialog as top most or set the parent/owner?

Tags: c#, file-io, filesystems, owner, topmost

When I call the following line, the dialog will show behind any floating dialogs, so I need to be able to set it to top most, or at least set the owner:

```
FileSystem.DeleteFile(someString, UIOption.AllDialogs, RecycleOption.SendToRecycleBin);
```

Unfortunately, I haven't found anything online that suggests this is doable. I understand I can create my own window and call into the API directly, but first I wanted to know if there was a way for all FileSystem dialogs to show topmost.

Comment: maybe set topmost on the window that calls deletefile then set it back again. the delete file dialog comes from windows itself its not like openfiledialog or savefiledialog

Comment: I already have a window that calls the line above. I've set the window to top most, it doesn't make a difference. Either way it's showing behind the window right now (between the window and the MainWindow).

Comment: Are you referring to the VB compat `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO` namespace?

Comment: The native COM interface, [`IFileOperation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775771.aspx) supports an owner window for the progress dialogs.

Comment: Yeah that's the namespace we are using. I'll look into IFileOperation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No answer, so I just set the messagebox parent to the form that's calling Show and just made API calls to recycle the deleted file:

```
            string message = string.Format("Are you sure you want to move '{0}' to the recycling bin?", Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path));
            var result = MessageBox.Show(this, message, @"Move To Recycling Bin?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                Send(path, FileOperationFlags.FOF_NOCONFIRMATION | FileOperationFlags.FOF_NOERRORUI | FileOperationFlags.FOF_SILENT);
            }
```

Where the method "send" is part of a wrapper class exposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282418/send-a-file-to-the-recycle-bin)