# System.IO.Directory.Delete Method just sends files to Recycling Bin. Any way to permanently delete?

Tags: c#, .net, system.io.directory

In .NET, I'm running the code `Directory.Delete(tempdir, true);` to permanently delete a directory and all contained files. This delete method only sends the files to recycling bin however, instead of permanently deleting them. Is there any way to force `Directory.Delete` to perma-delete the directory and contained files instead of just moving to recycle bin? I couldn't find any other method overloads to do this.

**EDIT:** As Neil pointed out, this is not what is actually happening. `Directory.Delete` is indeed permanently deleting the directory and contained files and not sending them to Recycle Bin. *Sorry for any confusion*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [MSDN:FileSystem.DeleteDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms127971.aspx).
It has the parameter `RecycleOption recycle` which uses the [enum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.recycleoption.aspx) with the following options:

- DeletePermanently
- SendToRecycleBin

So calling the following would be sufficient:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteDirectory(
  DirectoryPath,
  FileIO.UIOption.AllDialogs,
  FileIO.RecycleOption.DeletePermanently);
```

Comment: I'm curious about a few things concerning this library:
1.) Does `FileSystem.DeleteDirectory` method work in .NET even though it's from the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` package?
and 2.) Does this method delete the files contained within the directory as well? I didn't see any parameters that hinted whether it would or not.

Comment: Sure, VisualBasic is .NET compatible.
Yes, it does delete the directory and all files within but you can specify that behaviour (`FileIO.DeleteDirectoryOption.ThrowIfDirectoryNonEmpty`, see the doc).

Comment: Ah, thank you! I missed that part in the documentation. Sorry for the trivial question. I'm a bit new to C# so I wasn't sure how compatible .NET and VB were. Cheers!

Answer (score 10):

Are you sure this is actually what is happening?  There is nothing on the [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxeahc5f(v=vs.110).aspx) about this behaviour (and it wouldn't be very cross-platform if it did). Using system functionality like recycle bin usually involves some more complicated API functions than a simple delete.

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282418/send-a-file-to-the-recycle-bin)  implies the exact opposite of your question.

Comment: Indeed! I just tested it. `Directory.Delete(path, true);` doesn't move the folder to the recycling bin and instead deletes it straight away.

Comment: Actually, yes you're right. I also tested it again and it does seem to permanently delete. I see deleted temp directories in my Recycle Bin though so I'm a bit puzzled.  I must have manually deleted some files during unit testing.