# Send folder to Linux rubbish bin in C#

Tags: c#, linux, recycle-bin

I use the FileOperationAPIWrapper that can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282418/send-a-file-to-the-recycle-bin) to move files to the recycle bin on Windows with great success. I'm looking for how to do the same on Linux in C#.

Perhaps the Linux trash is a static folder that I can simply move folders to?

Comment: Not all linux systems have a recycle bin concept.

Comment: If the folder is static on those that do I could make use of it only if present, or delete straight out if not?

Answer (score 1):

Putting a file or directory in the trash requires more than just moving the file to a specific directory. How the trash functionality is implemented on Linux is specified by [FreeDesktop.org](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/trash-spec/trashspec-1.0.html). It's important to create the metadata ".trashinfo" files otherwise file recovery from the trashcan won't work since the original location the file was deleted from is unknown.