# Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.DeleteDirectory versus Directory.Delete

Tags: .net, directory

I stumbled upon this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564229/microsoft-visualbasic-fileio-filesystem-equivalence-in-c) while researching on the Delete Directory options available under:

1. Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.DeleteDirectory
2. Directory.Delete

Is this statement true?

> "Anyone says referencing the Microsoft.VisualBasic is often undesirable from within C#. Any association with VB from within C# code strikes me as undesirable"

Comment: Which one is your question? The difference between `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.DeleteDirectory` and `System.IO.Directory.Delete` or the subjective bit about referencing Microsoft.VisualBasic from C#? I hope the former.

Comment: No the latter - subjective bit.I was wondering what would be the issue, since referencing a .Net module (Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem) does not necesserily mean that I am using a Visual Basic code, though the namespace name has the term "VisualBasic" in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with referencing `Microsoft.VisualBasic` from any .NET language. I mean, other than uneasy feelings about its name.

It contains several methods to help porting VB6 code, but it also includes a couple of interesting shortcuts, like say, the [`AssemblyInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.assemblyinfo.aspx) class. If you're using Windows Forms, you can gain something if you inherit from [`WindowsFormsApplicationBase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms127621.aspx) (like easy single-instance applications, or splash screens).

Comment: Thank you Martinho... I have been using this class for a while, and then saw the post quoted before.

Answer (score 1):

Correct. The VisualBasic library is included primarily for backwards compatibility. It is greatly preferred (and probably more efficient) to use synonymous methods that are in the standard .NEt library.

Edit: But of course, for the linked post... when there is no equivalence, it's 'OK' to use the VisualBasic library

Comment: Thank you Zhais. From what I could dig in, Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.DeleteDirectory was introduced from Framework 2.0 and it is still being supported in 4.0.